# SQL Query for sorting by number of identical values in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sum

I am attempting to write an sql query for Postgresql that looks through a table of descriptions for a subject and another table that keeps tally of how many likes or dislikes or other flags are attached to the description. I want it to go through the tally table, find all the flags attached to each description, find the sum of how many identical flags there are for each description, then order by the number of likes each flag has minus how many dislikes etc it has, then return a list of all descriptions ordered by the sum of the previously described equation ( likes - dislikes etc.) and the number of likes, dislikes, etc. this is an example of the code I have so far ( there are more variables in the likes/dislikes as variable section ):

```
        SELECT likes, dislikes, positive - negative AS orderCondition
        FROM( SELECT d.id, d.l_id, d.user_id, d.description, a.flaggee_id,
        SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id = 1 THEN 1 WHEN actions_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS positive,
        SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id <> 1 THEN 1 WHEN a.actions_id <> 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS negative,
        SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS likes,
        SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS dislikes
        FROM descriptions d, description_actions a
        WHERE d.id = a.flaggee_id OR d.id > 0 AND d.id <> a.flaggee_id
        GROUP BY d.id, a.flaggee_id ) as result
        ORDER BY orderCondition DESC;
```

this is not working however, it returns an empty set without errors. data in the tables are random for testing, id's are integers, things that are not id's are random strings, when querying the tables individually the results are accurate, so its not a case of the data not being in the tables. I'm having a really difficult time figuring it out.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Describe what is the problem - is it a DB error? unexpected results?

Comment: "*is not working*" is not a valid Postgres error message. And please add some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: sorry, I thought it might be obvious to someone more experienced by looking at the code. the query returns empty set

Comment: added this to description, let me now if it is not adequate... "it returns an empty set without errors. data in the tables are random for testing, id's are integers, things that are not id's are random strings, when querying the tables individually the results are accurate, so its not a case of the data not being in the tables."

Comment: Can you verify that there is at least one row in your sample data for which `d.id = a.flaggee_id OR d.id > 0 AND d.id <> a.flaggee_id` is true? I'd recommend throwing in parentheses (`d.id = a.flaggee_id OR (d.id > 0 AND d.id <> a.flaggee_id)`) for readability. Also, if you want the description to show up in your results, you'll have to add it to the outer SELECT statement.

Comment: wouldn't  ``d.id = a.flaggee_id OR d.id > 0 AND d.id <> a.flaggee_id`` always be true as long as their is data in the description table? if there is no matching id in the flags table to the description id, then get any description that doesn't match and isn't zero basically is what I expect that statement to do.. is that incorrect?

Comment: if not then no, otherwise yes, there is data in the descriptions table

Comment: Is there at least one row in `d` in which `id` > 0? Is there at least one row in `a` in which `flaggee_id` is not NULL? ... and `actions_id` is not NULL? BTW, the logic you have will give you a separate row in the result set for *every* combination of d.id and a.flagee_id that aren't identical. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to specify that it was a left join, in order to still display results if the flags table was empty, I also added variables to the outer select. here is the working query

```
SELECT description, likes, dislikes, positive - negative AS orderCondition
FROM( SELECT d.id, d.l_id, d.user_id, d.description AS description, a.flaggee_id,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id = 1 THEN 1 WHEN actions_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS positive,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id <> 1 THEN 1 WHEN a.actions_id <> 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS negative,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS likes,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.actions_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS dislikes
FROM descriptions d LEFT JOIN description_actions a ON a.flaggee_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id, a.flaggee_id ) as result
ORDER BY orderCondition DESC;
```